# SQL insert names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Exercise: I need to make a selection of the first and last names of people, but at the same time there are appeals in the form of Dr., Mrs. and Mr.

How can I make the first_name column contain regular names and names starting with "Dr", "Mrs" and "Mr" and the last_name column contain only last names?

source table: raw_data.sales

| id | person_name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morgan Bell | +1-065-371-2672x2556 |
| 2 | Mr. Connor Thompson | +1-263-648-6239x95102 |
| 3 | Mr. Joseph Mitchell | (260)432-1831x60158 |
| 4 | Nathaniel Taylor | (076)030-9281 |
| ... | ... | ... |

My SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(person_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', person_name) - 1) AS first_name,
    SUBSTRING(person_name, CHARINDEX(' ', person_name) + 1, LEN(person_name) - CHARINDEX(' ', person_name)) AS last_name,
    phone
FROM raw_data.sales
```

table with current query: Client

| id | first_name | last_name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morgan | Bell | +1-065-371-2672x2556 |
| 2 | Mr. | Connor Thompson | +1-263-648-6239x95102 |
| 3 | Mr. | Joseph Mitchell | (260)432-1831x60158 |
| 4 | Nathaniel | Taylor | (076)030-9281 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

it should be like this:

| id | first_name | last_name | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Morgan | Bell | +1-065-371-2672x2556 |
| 2 | Mr. Connor | Thompson | +1-263-648-6239x95102 |
| 3 | Mr. Joseph | Mitchell | (260)432-1831x60158 |
| 4 | Nathaniel | Taylor | (076)030-9281 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Is that second table you've shown your expected result? Or what you're getting with your current query? I'm kind of assuming it's your current query. Can you include your expected results?

Comment: @Xedni I get with the current request

Comment: Please include your expected output. I think I understand your request reasonably well, but it would be good to be sure.

Comment: So what is the problem or error that you are facing?

Comment: Is there always a `.` followed by a space after the honorific?

Comment: What's your expected output for a person with a last name (or first name, for that matter) that contains spaces? Van Laethem, for example.

Comment: @Xedni Yes, there is always a . followed by a space

Comment: Imagine you could have suffixes too...  `Dr. Henry Van Winkle Jr.`

Comment: Important reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: The only real solution is fix the problem at the source; stop storing the names as one value to start with. For names you've alread stored you need to fix those manually, perhaps by talking the the individual when it's ambiguous.

Comment: How would you know which words are the first names and which ones are last names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the addition of what you have tried. If it is feasible for you you can use CASE Statements in your query. As you mentioned in your comment that you will always have '.' for salutation, then you can try below solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  id,
  case when person_name not like '%.%' then SUBSTRING(person_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', person_name) - 1) 
       else SubString(person_name, 1, CharIndex(' ', person_name, CharIndex(' ', person_name) + 1)) 
       End as first_name,
  case when person_name not like '%.%' then SUBSTRING(person_name, CHARINDEX(' ', person_name) + 1, LEN(person_name) - CHARINDEX(' ', person_name))
       else right(person_name, charindex(' ', reverse(person_name)) - 1)
       End as last_name,
    phone
FROM raw_data.sales
```

See the db fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/YLqMu8Kb

Answer (score 0):

So let me first caution you by saying doing this kind of name manipulation in SQL (or really, *anywhere*) is fraught with edge cases which can and will bite you. Just looking at the phone number examples, I can tell a lot of this is manually input data with little quality control. That means you're probably going to run into bad data in your name fields as well.

So the *CORRECT* way to do this is capture that data in distinct fields from the get go. Have those inputting the data be responsible for properly capturing first, middle, last, honorific, etc.

That said, let's take your question at face value, and write some code. So, at least given the sample data provided and the constraints mentioned in the comments, here's an approach that works. **Just remember, there are innumerable edge cases which can and will crop up which will probably break this code.**

This assumes that you will only have the pattern ". " immediately following an honorific at the start of the string. If that assumption is violated, this all goes out the window.

Ok. Have I given enough caveats? Good. Let's write some code.

First, I'm saving off the `patindex` of the ". " in the `cross apply` so I can reference it repeatedly. If the name doesn't contain ". ", it will be 0, which is exactly what I want.

Then I'm selecting the `FirstName` by getting the `charindex` of the first space after the `patindex` plus 2 (two extra characters, one for the period, and one for the space). (recall that if there wasn't an honorific, that index will basically be ignored).

To get the `LastName`, it's basically the same except you use the `PatIdx` as your start index, and then the length is just whatever big number you need to get the rest of the string.

```
drop table if exists #names
select Id, Name
into #names
from
(
    values
    (1, 'Morgan Bell'),
    (2, 'Mr. Connor Thompson'),
    (3, 'Mr. Joseph Mitchell'),
    (4, 'Nathaniel Taylor')
) a (Id, name)

select Id, Name,
    FirstName = substring
    (
        Name,
        1,
        charindex(' ', name, PatIdx + 2) -- Plus 2 for the period and the space
    ),
    LastName = substring
    (
        name,
        charindex(' ', name, PatIdx + 2),
        len(name)
    )
from #names a
cross apply
(
    -- I put in this condition because if a name starts with a period
    -- followed by a space, it puts the period in the last name
    select PatIdx = iif(patindex('%. %', name) = 0, -2, patindex('%. ', name))
) b
```

Some edge cases to consider:

- What if someone's first name has more than one part?
- What if someone provides an honorific without the period?
- What if the honorific is at the end of their name?
- What if ". " appears somewhere else in their name?
- What if they have multiple honorifics?

**EDIT**
Do read the article Charlieface posted on [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)